# All metafields fetched via Shopify API got improper owner and all belong to "shop"

Tags: json, shopify

I got problem with shopify API and with data it provides. When i try to get list of all meta-fields with my app I end up with invalid data that tell **all** meta-fields are owned by **shop** (`owner_id`, `owner_resource` in JSON result). In shop I work with there is over 2000 meta-fields, created mostly by installed apps, that most certainly belong directly to resources like **page**, **blog** or **product** and most of them are most certain not associated directly with **shop**.

What is more strange when i use **chrome plugins** or **free shopify app** to edit meta-fields, that in data i recieve present as associated with **shop**, they are displayed as belonging to particular aspects of shop as it should be. Adding or deleting meta-field does not reflect on the data or count of meta-fields I get in way explained below.

So what I do first is getting count of metafields with following request, to later know how split data requests into pages.

```
/admin/metafields/count.json
```

then to get complete set of data i make series of requests like this

```
/admin/metafields.json?limit=200&page=1
...
```

As result i get (example data)

```
{   "id": 2488777,   "namespace": "content_value",   "key": "[default]3883205",   "value": "There are no items in your cart. ",   "value_type": "string",   "description": "",   "owner_id": 2174481,   "created_at": "2014-12-30T20:23:56+01:00",   "updated_at": "2014-12-30T20:33:56+01:00",   "owner_resource": "shop" }
```

So my question is what wrong I do here making these requests and why i get invalid data, or it is maybe another "shopify thing" to get such behaviour. Can someone direct me how to get full valid list of meta-fields with rightfully associated owners? Is there any caching involved with metafields that could cause lack of update?

Answer (score 0):

When you make a call to `/admin/metafields.json` without any query parameters then you will see the metafields that belong to the shop.

You can retrieve metafields that belong to another resource by making an authenticated `GET` request to a URL like this one: `/admin/orders/3250063171/metafields.json`

An alternate format for the URL is this: `/admin/metafields.json?metafield[owner_id]=3250063171&metafield[owner_resource]=order`

Comment: But why I do notice metafields that belong to other shop resource assigned to shop? Is there way to get all metafields with their owners in one go without giving resource type and ID? if not then results of `/admin/metafields.json` are rubbish and in fact it should only return metafields that are really assigned to shop or am I missing something and there is reason for such result being returned?